# JAXBException occurred : unexpected element while calling Rest Service from Postman client

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, cxf

I have a rest service written using Spring and CXF. The method is shown below.

```
@POST
@Path("/detail")
public StudentResponse getStudentDetails(Student student);
```

The Student Class.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Student")
public class Student implements Serializable{
...
```

I am able to call the service using a cxf client

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8180/oauthserver/service/student/detail");
            client.type("application/json").accept("application/json");
            Response response =client.post(s);

            StudentResponse sr = response.readEntity(StudentResponse.class);
```

The data i am posting(Used jackson to generate the json entry)

```
  {
      "name" : "input",
      "id" : 1,
      "marks" : 20.2
    }
```

But while calling the service from PostMan for SoapUI i am getting the below error.

```
        JAXBException occurred : unexpected element (uri:"", local:"name"). 
    Expected elements are <{}Student>.
 unexpected element (uri:"", local:"name"). Expected elements are <{}Student>.
```

I am calling as POST method and context type RAW.I have set the header values to this:

```
Content-Type : application/json
Accept : application/json
```

But still its not working. Any pointers?

Comment: What happens if you use `{ "Student" : { .... } }`. As an aside, I don't think Jackson is being used. I'd imagine that Jackson should not have errors about JAXBExceptions

Comment: Thanks . Adding Student in the front solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting this for any one facing the same issue.

I had to add the jackson provider to the service listing

```
<jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>
```

then needed to add the maven dependency (The newer version will have a different package dependency)

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

This page had the solution...
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html